# Magit magit-diff-refine-hunk does not work if I don't move the cursor to the good lines

Tags: magit, diff

In magit, it looks like that if I want to have a diff that highlight changing words, I can either press `D t` when I'm in the diff, or put in my .emacs

```
(custom-set-variables '(magit-diff-refine-hunk all))
```

However, it turns out that the changing words are highlighted only if I move the buffer cursor near to the line that changed. So for example if I have two changes in the file, then I need to move my cursor to the diff of the second part of the file to see the changes.

Can I set it up so that the refine diff is displayed across all the buffer ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are not using `custom-set-variables` correctly. You are not supposed to write that by hand, but if you wrote it like this

```
(custom-set-variables '(magit-diff-refine-hunk (quote all)))
```

then it should work. But just use this instead

```
(setq magit-diff-refine-hunk 'all)
```

As mentioned by @Basil, you could also use `custom-set-variable` (singular), but that only makes sense if setting the option through the Custom interface would do something beside setting the variable, i.e. if the `defcustom` sets `:initialize`, `:set` or `:set-after'. Since that isn't the case here you should just use`setq'.

Comment: FWIW, the hand-written version of `custom-set-variables` for a single variable is `customize-set-variable`.